# How to handle a parameter that has no value in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that has two datasets in it.  The first dataset is used to populate a parameter to a second dataset.  Everything works fine until the first dataset has no values, whereupon I get a parameter X is missing a value message.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using [Cascading Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337169%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), you can use a query similar to the following to populate the second parameter's DataSet:

```
if exists (select 1 from Param2 where paramVal = @Param1)
begin

    select paramVal, paramDetail
    from Param2
    where paramVal = @Param1

end
else
begin

    select paramVal = 'None', paramDetail = 'None'

end
```

This is just a workaround using an `if...else` construct to return a dummy row if there aren't any other rows to return - that way you'll always get at least one row returned even if there are no matches for the first parameter value.

You can handle these dummy rows as required later in the report.

As above this is a workaround to address your specific issue, but hopefully will be of some help.

**Added after comment:**

I just tested now - it works just the same with multi-valued parameters; just change `=@Param1` to `in (@Param1)`.

If there are one or more matches in the second DataSet it returns those rows, otherwise just the dummy row.

I did need to shut/reopen the report in VS, but that could have been unrelated.

Comment: That's not quite what I am doing.  The parameter I am using gets a list of values from Dataset #1 for a specified field in that dataset. The second dataset uses this SQL to get its values:
    Select field1, field2
    from mytable
    where (field1 in (@parameter1))

Comment: It's the same principle; did you give it a try? Assuming that works, is the dummy row approach suitable for you?

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: It worked when I applied this method to the first dataset.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @IanPreston If I may ask, is there any way to achieve the same using Fetchxml. I mean I need rows returing from Dataset if not I need empty "dumy value". But I am using Datasource as Fetchxml.