# SSRS query report parameter visibility when there is no value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have one report with 4 multi valued parameters where the values populates based on which value is chosen from the first parameter:

Example: `@Param1 = Forest, @Param2 = Lake , @Param3 = Fish`

Depending on the values selected, the last parameter might not have a value.

Example: `@Param1 = Desert, @Param2 = Sand, @Param3 = Null (Empty)`

In this case, having `@param3` visible in Reporting Services just displays an empty parameter box, and the user starts to wonder if there is missing data and so on.

How can I have the empty @Param3 get some kind of disabled in t-sql code?

This is the query for @param3:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column3
FROM TABLE
WHERE Column1 = (@param1) AND
Column2 = (@param2)
ORDER BY Column3
```

The main dataset query has this predicate:

```
FROM TABLE
WHERE (Column1 = (@param1) or (@param1) is not null) AND
       Column2 = (@param2) or (@param2) is not null)
      AND (Column3 IN (@Param3) OR (@Param3) !='') AND 
(Column4 IN (@param4)) OR (@param4 !='')
ORDER BY Month
```

.

Comment: We're not blind, at least not all of us...

Comment: Dont forget, not blind and not funny...however there is other forums for this kind of comments dont forget that either.

Comment: Format your posting without those `#`, and it will be much easier to read it. Don't make it difficult to help you.

Comment: Post the code you are using to populate the parameter options - it should be possible to include a 'No Value Needed' option when there is no data to return.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle a parameter that has no value in SSRS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151353/how-to-handle-a-parameter-that-has-no-value-in-ssrs)

Comment: i dont get your requirement properly. do u need to populate @Param3 with some value like 'all'  if it is null?

Comment: one possible option is you can hide the parameter if it null using the expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a 'dummy' value to your script, and only returning it when there are no other values available:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column3
FROM TABLE
WHERE 
    Column1 = (@param1) AND
    Column2 = (@param2)
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'No Value Needed'
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1
    FROM TABLE 
    WHERE 
        Column1 = (@param1) AND
        Column2 = (@param2)
  )
ORDER BY Column3
```

Comment: Hi @Henrik if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: HI @AHiggins actually it doesn't resolved the problem but I liked it and it resolved half way, still it gives error that parameter is missing.